# How to make maven enforcer plugin to run in a specified phase?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-enforcer-plugin

I would like to ensure the file size of resulting zip file is not larger than 400 MB so I've created this rule:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-file-size</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce-once</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireFilesSize>
                  <maxsize>419430400</maxsize> <!-- the final zip should not exceed 400 MB -->
                  <files>
                   <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}.zip</file>
                  </files>
                </requireFilesSize>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

However, the *mvn enforcer* is by default bound to the `validate` phase and unfortunately the file does not exist by this time. The zip file is generated by ant task that is bound to `generate-resources` mvn phase.

**Question**

Is there any way to make the *mvn enforcer* to run after `generate-resources`? Or to put it another way, how can I verify a build **post-condition** instead pre-condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

omg, adding `<phase>verify</phase>` worked for me:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-file-size</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce-once</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireFilesSize>
              <maxsize>419430400</maxsize> <!-- the final zip should not exceed 400 MB -->
              <files>
               <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}.zip</file>
              </files>
            </requireFilesSize>
          </rules>
          <fail>true</fail>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Delete me, I am ashamed :)

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer.  You have no idea how much headache this saved me.